Large disparity in Spyder GUI font sizes when accessed via chained RDP sessions
I can get reasonable font sizes in Spyder when:

I am working on an on-site desktop (machine A) connected to widescreen displays
I'm working directly on an on-site laptop display (machine B).
I RDP from machine A to machine B

My situation is that I can't constraint the wide difference in font sizes when I RDP from an off-site laptop to machine A, and from there, RDP to machine B (both RDPs in full screen).  The pixel counts for all displays are the same: 1920x1080 for off-site laptop, machine A [1], and machine B.
I tried Spyder's Screen Resolution options: Normal, High DPI, and custom scaling for High DPI.  For the latter, I tried 1.25x scaling, which appears to be a middle ground between Normal and High DPI (High DPI seems to match a scaling of 1.5x).
In all cases, the fonts for tabs in each pane and the paths seems unreadably tiny.  Spyder's font specifications don't seem to affect such text.
Are there any other controls that I can try to make the unreadably tiny fonts bigger?
Unlike this Q&A, I only get this problem in the double-RDP setup described above.

Notes
[1] Machine A doesn't have built-in displays, it connects to external displays of the same pixel counts (1920x1080).  So the displays for machine A probably aren't relevant when I RDP into machine A and, from there, RDP to machine B.  Empirically, it seems that RDP simply conveys the local display size to the remote machine.  If so, then in the chained RDP sessions, the off-site laptop's display size is conveyed to machine A, which in turn conveys it to machine B.  Again, I'm not sure how relevant this is because all display sizes are the same.  The only information that machine B might be missing is whether the off-site display is High DPI, but that's the main Spyder control that I experiment with (above).
